# How many of those surveyed did not watch any of the three sports?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

A survey of 500 viewers in a metropolitan television market shows that 285 viewers watched football games, 195 watched baseball, and 115 watched soccer. The survey showed that 45 watched football and baseball, 75 watched football and soccer, 50 watched baseball and soccer, and 32 watched all three sports.

One time I had 297 and another time 203... It confused me, can you help me?

Comment: Recall that $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$.  All of these values on the right were given to you in the problem statement.  This allows you to figure out the value on the left.

Comment: Ok, thank you, so if I understand 500-457=43 right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.